# SSIS unable to process cube after upgrade to SQL Server 2016 sp2

Tags: ssis, ssas, sql-server-2016

Code developed in Visual Studio to process cubes stopped working.  No changes have been made to the code and this is happening for a number of packages which were developed for this purpose within the project.

We recently upgraded from SQL Server 2016 CU8 to SQL Server 2016 SP2.  After upgrading, SSIS packages which perform cube processing functions throw the following error:

Error Code: 0  Description:   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This has happened on two servers we upgraded in our lower environments.  Anyone else experiencing this or heard anything from MS?  There was a posting on the community PowerBI board about this issue yesterday, but it seems to have been pulled.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that we are having the same problem after installing SP2. A similar problem with CU5 for sql server 2017 is discussed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/515c90a5-690f-4397-ac2a-80301aa96438/sql2017-cu5-microsoftanalysisservicesadomdclientui-could-not-load-file-or-assembly?forum=sqlintegrationservices I tried the solution suggested there, i.e. finding a copy of adomdclientui.dll on the server and copying it to the place the system is looking for it, but the version I have doesn't seem to be the expected one. I have tried using version 13.0.1701.8

Comment: Any updates on this? Has it been fixed in the latest CU? This is on-topic for me.

Comment: I just applied SP2 CU2 (v.13.0.5153.0) and this seems to be resolved.

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot thanks for the input, I am having the same issue, and will apply CU2